# How can I determine type of mysql database : whether it is InnoDB or MyISAM?

Tags: sql, mysql, types

- How can I determine type of mysql database : whether it is InnoDB or MyISAM ?
- How can I convert MyISAM to InnoDB or vice-versa ?

Comment: Do you use any database managing system? Like phpMyAdmin or SQLyog?

Comment: No. I am not using any database management system.

Comment: I am trying alter table the_table engine = InnoDB; but it appears that engine is not changed, is it because I do not have right or what might be the reason for it ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To determine the storage engine being used by a table, you can use [`show table status`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html).  The `Engine` field in the results will show the database engine for the table.  Alternately, you can select the `engine` field from [`information_schema.tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html):

```
select engine 
from   information_schema.tables 
where  table_schema = 'schema_name'
   and table_name = 'table_name'
```

You can change between storage engines using [`alter table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
alter table the_table engine = InnoDB;
```

Where, of course, you can specify any available storage engine.

Comment: I am trying alter table the_table engine = InnoDB; but it appears that engine is not changed, is it because I do not have right or what might be the reason for it ?

Comment: "If a storage engine does not support an attempted ALTER TABLE operation, a warning may result. Such warnings can be displayed with SHOW WARNINGS"

Answer (score 19):

Select the database in question and run `show table status;`

Answer (score 6):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database`;
```

will list everything for all tables, starting with whether they are MyISAM or InnoDB.  if you desire to list only data regarding 1 table, the syntax below may be used* :

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database` LIKE 'table';
```

to change the table engine:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

*attention use the GRAVE ACCENT (` backtick) for the database name and the table name and the SINGLE QUOTE (') for the comparison string (portion of table name) after LIKE.

> `   !=   '

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that lists **all** tables in **all** databases and their storage engines:

```
SELECT table_name, table_schema, engine
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

(From https://serverfault.com/a/244792/406647)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding converting myIsam to Innodb

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Answer (score 0):

[How can I determine type of mysql database : whether it is InnoDB or MyISAM?](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/find-storage-engine-of-mysql-table-2009-09-17/)