# Better/Fast way to search 81k+ cities and in a suggestion combobox from json/mySQL

Tags: php, json, autocomplete

Ok. the problem is - the code you're about to see is working 100% However, it take forever to start showing the suggestions. I notice if I can adapt it to start search only after 5th character it will load MUCH faster. I adapted this code from https://daveismyname.com/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui-bp

I though since I am dealing with more than 81 thousand of lines mySQL will be faster. Right now I am in a localhost. This data was import from a public records with all cities of USA.

question 1: Do you think after upload to my web host will be better?

question 2: is there a better way to get this work faster

question 3: how can I test if $_POST is more than 5 digits

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <p><label>City or Zip Code: </label><input type='text' name='city' class='auto'></p>
    </form>
<!-- Those lines are mandatory in order to use JQuery and JQuery UI  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });

});
</script>
```

**SEARCH.PHP**

```
<?php
// https://daveismyname.com/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui-bp
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'us_cities');
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country LIKE :term');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        // BE AWARE
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['city'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: if you drop the leading %(wildcard) in the hope they can spell somewhat, and term is indexed, it will be a lot faster. min length of 1 seems silly 3 maybe.

Comment: mySQL has just 1 table with 81+K with just 1 row as: cityName, State ZIP. Do you think break down the table in 3 row as cityname, state, zipcode will be better?

Comment: if they are not going to search on zip-code, then it shouldn't be in the field searched.

Comment: Thanks Dagon. I just re-import the .csv and I break down in 3 separate row as: city - state - zipcode.

I have no idea how to do the %(wildcard) will be possible for you write this piece for me?

Comment: Dagon meant that instead of doing `WHERE city LIKE %term%` as you currently do, you can do `WHERE city LIKE term%`.  This means that it will find a match so long as the user started typing at the beginning of the city name.  I don't think its a good idea, but I agree that it would make the query faster

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. After the user enters a character, the following cause most of the latency

1. The time to connect to the server and send the query
2. The time it takes PHP to connect to DB and execute query

So to have a significant effect, your measures should reduce the number of connections to the server, reduce the number of DB executions, or use faster DB queries. There are at least 3 approaches you can take to dramatically reduce latency. They can even be combined.

**Approach 1: speed up your DB queries**

1. Change your DB table structure so the `cities` field have an index of type FULLTEXT. These are specifically design to [speed up text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html). Thiis requires that your table use the InnoDB storage engine, rather than the older MyISAM. To figure out what you have or to change it, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638070/how-can-i-determine-type-of-mysql-database-whether-it-is-innodb-or-myisam)
2. Change your SQL queries to use `MATCH() AGAINST` to search rather than `LIKE`.  For example: `SELECT city FROM cities WHERE MATCH(city) AGAINST ('term')`. [More info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html).  You need to have done step 1 for this to work

**Approach 2: reduce number of http requests**

1. Add a `STATE` dropdown in your form, and a `STATE` field to your DB. When the user selects a state, make a query that fetches all city names within that state to the browser. This will be 1 or 2,000 records. If you gzip-compress the result before returning it to the browser, the result will be under 100KB.  There will be latency for the user at this point, but it won't be a big deal because the user is not yet typing a city name and waiting for autocomplete.
2. Now that you have the results in the browser as a Javascript array of cities, you can provide the array to the `autocomplete` function of `jQueryUI`.  Set the `minLength` to 3 and the autocomplete latency will be so short that the user won't perceive it.

**Approach 3: reduce number of DB queries**

If you don't want to download a big block of results, you could take another approach; autocomplete won't be as fast as with the previous, but it will be faster than you currently experience:

1. Install and use an in-memory cache. If you cache all cities in memory, you'll be able to find your results fast without querying the database. I would look at PHP's [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) extensions for good options. In my own research, I found the 2nd to be more feature-complete, but I chose the 1st because it's the only one I could get to run on Windows (on my dev machine)
2. When a query comes in, 1st check whether the `cities` list is already in the cache. If it is, use `array_filter()` to create and `echo` the array of matches. If `cities` is not in the cache, execute a DB query to load all cities in the cache, then use `array_filter()` as above. You can save even more time by adding a `STATE` input, a `STATE` field in the DB, and storing each state's cities as a different entry in the cache. So when a user searches for a city in New York, you don't have to run `array_filter()` on all 81,000 cities.

My own suggestion is that you combine all 3 approaches (unless bandwidth is a big concern, in which case you may want to skip #2). The 3rd approach is a bit of work because it requires some research and installation, but once you have a working cache, you'll find that you can use it to speed up a lot of operations for slow-moving data (eg: city names don't change much) that you used to query the DB for.